# Mongo DB bulk insert using javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, bulkinsert

I am working on a project that uses mongo db. I want to copy the documents from one collection to another which satisfies a query condition. I am using bulk operation for doing the same. Before calling execute method on bulkInsert object, we need to add each document from source collection which is taking time. My question is, is there any way by which we can directly add the result of the query from on collection into the bulkInsert object? Following is what I have done.

```
    bulkInsert = db.targetCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulkRemove = db.sourceCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

db.sourceCollection.find({"time":{$lt: date}}).forEach(function(doc) {

  bulkInsert.insert(doc);

  counter ++;

  if( counter % batchSize == 0){
    bulkInsert.execute();
    bulkRemove.execute();
    bulkInsert = db.targetCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

    print("Inserted " + counter + " documents in " + targetCollection);
    }

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "directly insert"? This is basically how you do it. If you are expecting a kind of `select .. insert into ..` syntax that all happens on the server, then mongodb does not have that. Also why not just [`db.cloneCollection()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/) and  then remove data from each by a simple range selection? Or even just use [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) with `.aggregate()`? Both really simple solutions.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I will try out what you are suggesting. "Directly insert" meaning instead of inserting each object from result cursor into bulkInsert object, is there any way to insert entire cursor data into bulkInsert?

Comment: Like I said, it does not exist. But the other two methods there **do** alow you to create a "new collection" with either all the output, or the output of a query respectively. Both of those can be done without any local network traffic.

Comment: I tried using cloneCollection, but it works when one needs to clone the collection between two different databases. In my case, I just want to copy some documents to another collection in the same database.

Comment: Hey Neil, $out worked!... Now it takes only a minute to copy almost 3.5 lacs documents! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I might be late and bit off road but an option is to mongoexport with --query option and then call mongoimport with the filtered json. Not a clean way but could be an alternative.